Encountering 'sassc-rails' Gem Load Error with Passenger and Apache
I'm experiencing an issue deploying my Ruby on Rails application using Passenger with Apache. The application fails to start due to a Gem Load Error related to sassc-rails. The error message is as follows:
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sassc-rails'.
Gem Load Error is:
/var/www/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.17.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ffi/function.rb:65:in `attach'
/var/www/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:40:in `attach_function'
/var/www/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `require_relative'
/var/www/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/www/myapp/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.6@myapp/gems/passenger-6.0.24/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'

Environment Details:
Ruby Version: 3.3.6
Rails Version: 8
Passenger Version: 6.0.24
sassc-rails Version: 2.1.2
ffi Version: 1.17.0

Steps Taken:
Rebuilt the sassc-rails Gem: Executed bundle pristine sassc-rails and gem install sassc-rails to ensure the gem is correctly installed.
Asset Precompilation: Ran rails assets:precompile, which completed successfully without errors.
Temporary Workaround: Commented out line 65 in the ffi gem's function.rb file. This allowed the server to start, but I understand this is not a proper solution.
Additional Information:
The application runs without issues in the development environment.
The problem arises only when deploying with Passenger and Apache.
I have verified that all system dependencies are up to date.
Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance on resolving this sassc-rails gem load error in a production environment using Passenger and Apache. Specifically, I would like to understand:
The root cause of this error.
Why commenting out line 65 in the ffi gem's function.rb file allows the server to start.
The correct approach to resolve this issue without modifying gem source code.
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

I would not be investing any effort into figuring out how a gem last updated 5 years ago can be made to work with the latest ruby and rails versions.  Moving to a currently supported gem would seem a better use of time.

To further on @dbugger's comment. The reason the gem hasn't been updated is that it's a wrapper around the LibSass parser written i C which was depreachiated back in 2020. The only currently supported parser is Dart-Sass.

I will try with dart sass
